# Bound on the total change using Pearson's r

Tags: regression, machine-learning, anova, mathematical-statistics

I am given an increasing series $(x_1,....x_n)$ and I know the pearson correlation between $(x_1,....x_n)$ and some (unknown) increasing series $(y_1,....y_n)$.

Can I derive an upper and a lower bound on $|y_n-y_1|$ using Pearson's r and $|x_n-x_1|$ and the variance of x any y?